# Display data from side by side input text box using cakephp 2.5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cakephp

i want to create and display side by side input text box which is min and max as shown as below:

```
Item Name        Min    Max
Item 1           23     33
Item 2           10     40
```

The min and max is an input text box which user can key-in the number, qty. My problem is i've created the view.ctp but when i try to insert the number in the column and click submit it will display on view.ctp but with wrong number but can save on database with correct key-in number. e.g when i key-in number 23 for min and 33 for max for Item 1 it will display 0 0 for both. I'm not sure the problem. Hope someone will guide me. Thanks in advance.

burner.ctp

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='column3'><span class='green_text'><b>Item Name</b></span></div>
    <div class='column2'><span class='green_text'><b>Min</b></span></div>
    <div class='column2'><span class='green_text'><b>Max</b></span></div>
</div>
<br />
<div class='row'><div class='column2'>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('B_Min_i01', array('label' => false, 'error' => false)); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->error('B_Min_i01'); ?>
</div>
<div class='column2'>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('B_Max_i01', array('label' => false, 'error' => false)); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->error('B_Max_i01'); ?>
</div>
```

BurnersController

```
if($this->Burner->save($this->request->data, array('validate' => false)))
{
    $table_name = 'Burner_L';
    $this->Burner->setSource($table_name);

    for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++)
    {
        if($i<10){
            $j = '0' . $i;
        } else { 
            $j = $i; 
        }

        $this->request->data['Burner']['Item_Name'] = $this->request->data['Burner']['Item_Name' . $j];
        $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Min'] = $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Min' . $j];
        $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Max'] = $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Max' . $j];
        $this->Burner->create();
        $this->Burner->ID = NULL;
        $save = $this->Burner->save($this->request->data, array('validate' => false));
    }

    if($save)
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The record has been saved.', 'success');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index_burner')); 
    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The records could not saved.', 'error');
    }
}
```

view_bur.ctp

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='column3'><label>Item 1</label></div>
    <div class='column2'> <?php echo $details[0]['Burner']['B_Min']<1?'0'. $details[1]['Burner']['B_Min']:$details[2]['Burner']['B_Min']; ?>&nbsp;</div>
    <div class='column2'> <?php echo $details[1]['Burner']['B_Max']<1?'0'. $details[1]['Burner']['B_Max']:$details[1]['Burner']['B_Max']; ?>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='column3'><label>Item 2</label></div>
    <div class='column2'> <?php echo $details[2]['Burner']['B_Min']<1?'0'. $details[2]['Burner']['B_Min']:$details[2]['Burner']['B_Min']; ?>&nbsp;</div>
    <div class='column2'> <?php echo $details[3]['Burner']['B_Max']<1?'0'. $details[3]['Burner']['B_Max']:$details[3]['Burner']['B_Max']; ?>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy controller code and check these lines:

```
$this->request->data['Burner']['B_Min'] = $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Min_i' . $j];
$this->request->data['Burner']['B_Max'] = $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Max_i' . $j];
```

---

```
if($this->Burner->save($this->request->data, array('validate' => false)))
{
    $table_name = 'Burner_L';
    $this->Burner->setSource($table_name);

    for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++)
    {
        if($i<10){
            $j = '0' . $i;
        } else { 
            $j = $i; 
        }

        $this->request->data['Burner']['Item_Name'] = $this->request->data['Burner']['Item_Name' . $j];
        $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Min'] = $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Min_i' . $j];
        $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Max'] = $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Max_i' . $j];
        $this->Burner->create();
        $this->Burner->ID = NULL;
        $save = $this->Burner->save($this->request->data, array('validate' => false));
    }

    if($save)
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The record has been saved.', 'success');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index_burner'));    
    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The records could not saved.', 'error');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment! Sorry, i've added _i at the back but still the same.